# How do I adjust log4j levels at runtime?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, runtime

I have a simple web app running on Tomcat 5.5 with log4j for logging. Occasionally I need to push the logging down to DEBUG but most of the time I'm happy with INFO.

I can change my config xml and restart the app but I would prefer to switch the log levels on the fly. Is there a standard technique for this?

Comment: consider exposing the logger via JMX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the programmatic [API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level)):

```
logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
```

in your program when you need more verbose logging output, and

```
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
```

to make it less verbose again.

Comment: If you're using weblogic they have a drop-in JSP that allows you to adjust all running loggers using this API.

Answer (score 5):

I created a new java application module (jar) to do this in a web interface at runtime, and also have a page to view the log result.
Configure the jar is very simple: must be placed in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, and add a mapping to the servlet in the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

Project site: http://www.log4jwebtracker.com