# Changing the log path on fly

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j for logging activities in my application.I want to take the log path from data base. 
 now I need to configure my log4j properties dynamically.

can we do it on the fly we change the log4h logging path..

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level for some approaches to changing the log config dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a class what loads at the startup and configurate the log4j.
Here is a code what I used in a JavaEE project, what loads the configuration file from an outer directory:

```
public class InitListener implements ServletContextListener {

public InitListener() {
}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
        File    file  = null;
        file = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/conf/query-log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(file.toURL());
        System.out.println("Log4J successfully configured!");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error when initialize the Log4J config!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
}
```

}

Comment: Hi,Thannks for the reply, my actual problem is how to change the log path on fly. i can not hard code the path in environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using [MentaLog](http://mentalog.soliveirajr.com), all you have to do was that:

```
yourLogger.setFilename("newfilenamehere.log");
```

Your log would be automatically re-opened with the new name. In my personal opinion, [programmatic configuration](http://mentalog.soliveirajr.com/posts/list/35.page) is the way to go over XML and/or annotations. It provides unmatched flexibility and easy of use.

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate properties file to hold *Specific Enviroment* related settings example:

```
**uatLog4j.properties**
#######################
UAT Settings
#######################

{Add your Settings here}
```

And another for sy production enviroment.

```
**productionLog4j.properties**
########################
PRODUCTION settings
########################

{Add your Settings here}
```

And then using say the *IP Address or the Server Name* to determine the deployed platform, pass the path from the database to the required enviroment properties file as required.

Alternatively you can use `LogManager` to retreive Logger instances or to operate on the current LoggerRepository. See [Javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html) and a [RepositorySelecter](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html) example.

NOTE:
You can achieve the same using XML.