# How can I override the log4j properties file in my jar at runtime

Tags: java, unix, jar, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically Changing log4j log level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level)

I have a **jar** file with a **log4j** properties file included. I tried to use

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:[filename]`

to change the properties file at *runtime* using
*java*, and it didn't work. I need to do this in a *sh* file 
Can anyone please tell me how to this? I also tried adding

```
-Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true
```

Comment: No, I need to do this using a sh file, and VM arguments. There seems to be a way to do this, I just can't get it to work

Comment: Actually, it is not a "runtime" it is "startup time". Have you tried path without `file:` prefix? Are you sure the file exists? According to the [doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure), your steps are valid..

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to override the log4j properties file at runtime.   You may fall into this situation if you cann't :

1. In your jar or somewhere in the code, the log4j system is initialised  manually, e.g.

   ```
    URL url=loader.getResource(LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE)
    DOMConfigurator.configure(url);
   ```

Comment: This helped! I had to use the default Java classloader instead of the log4j Loader thought. The latter wouldn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good,step-by-step tutorial (with good screenshots!) that shows a couple of different alternatives for changing your log4j settings at runtime:

- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-change-my-log4j-settings-while-my-web-application-is-running.html

Comment: Nice tutorial. However, it seems specific to webapps—please correct me if I'm wrong. I think the OP wants to launch their application from a shell script.

Comment: I use log4j all the time in standalone Java Swing and console-mode apps.  Exactly the same principles apply: just edit an appropriate log4j.properties file :)

Comment: Good old Swing. :-) So, you're talking about 'just' extracting the appropriate log4j.properties file from the jar, and then either rebuilding the jar, or running the exploded jar? That's a lot more work and mess than just setting a property in a script.