# weblogic log4j.xml changing the "level value" of a logger (on-the-fly)

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

I thought I had found a solution of being able to change a custom appender's level value on the fly by utilizing the jsp tag referenced here;

http://nayidisha.com/techblog/mycontent/posts/nd-utils/site/loggerAdmin.html

Unfortunately, the link is broken so I am unable to download the utility.  The article was from 2009 and appears to be an exact match for what I need. Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish?  Below is an example:

[log4j.xml] snippet

```
    <logger name="EXAMPLE_LOGGER" additivity="false">
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="EXXAMPLE_LOG_APPENDER" />
    </logger>
```

I am looking for some way to modify the "level value" on the fly without restarting the managed server or polling the log4j.xml file.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4598702/217324

Answer (score 1):

There is WebLogic logging library, that can do that. You can implement LOG4J Logger that utilizes this library. We have done this in previous job. I think this is the library: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm#i1011558

```
import weblogic.logging.log4j.Log4jLoggingHelper;
import weblogic.logging.LoggerNotAvailableException;
public class MyLog4jTest {
  public void testWLSLog4j() {
    try {
      Logger logger = Log4jLoggingHelper.getLog4jServerLogger();
      logger.addAppender(myAppender); // The Appender is configured using either the log4j props file or other custom mechanism.
      logger.info("Test log message");
    } catch(LoggerNotAvailableException lex) {
    System.err.println("Unable to get a reference to the log4j Logger: "+
  lex.getMessage())
    }
  }
}
```