# How can i turn off log4j for one line of code

Tags: java, grails, logging, log4j

I have one line of code printing warnings. I am aware of those and I can't do anything about them as they are bugs of the library i use. What I want to do is create an annotation that disables Logging of those warnings for just that method call.

If creating a method call doesn't work, I can also copy past it everywhere(sloppy, but..).

What i basically want to do is wrap the method call in a block that disables Logging with log4j and resets back.

Ideal impl

```
@ChangeLoggingLevelTo(Level.ERROR)
log.warn("this don't get logged")

log.warn("This however will be logged")
```

or something like this

```
SomeHelperClass.changeLoggingLevelTo(Level.ERROR)
log.warn("this don't get logged")

SomeHelperClass.resetLoggingLevel()//this will reset the level to the default
log.warn("This however will be logged")
```

I am on grails, there for getting the configured log level is not a trouble.

Comment: why are you defining it as WARN then? Why not debug?

Comment: The library makes a call to the warn! I am emulating that behavior!

Comment: You can have a look to these questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434252/programmatically-change-log-level-in-log4j2

Comment: This will be awkward in a multi-threaded system like Grails, as loggers and appenders are shared across all threads.  You'd need to use some sort of thread-local state such as the [MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) and write a custom Appender or Filter implementation that adjusts what it logs based on the value you put in the MDC.

Comment: If the log statements are in the library itself, why not just set the highest logger in the library's hierarchy to error in Config.groovy? eg

`warn 'com.mycompany.myapp'
error 'com.3rdparty.library'`