# is it possible to avoid error information in text.INFO file of log4j properties?

Tags: java

I am using log4j properties to capture the logs.i wants to remove error info from INFO file.

**

> INFO

** file is below:

5:39:02,068  INFO BluSyncLauncher:156 - Application started

05:39:02,080  INFO BluSyncLauncher:586 - Loading UI
05:39:02,263  INFO BackupCrawlDAOImpl:470 - sqlExeception in CREATE_ACTIVITY_TABLEjava.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (duplicate column name: IsFolder)

05:39:02,264 **

> ERROR

** BackupActivityHistoryDAOImpl:706 - sqlExeception in CREATE_ACTIVITY_TABLEjava.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (duplicate column name: restartid)
05:39:03,803  INFO BluSyncLauncher:533 - Started crawl (backup)
05:39:03,827  INFO BluSyncLauncher:543 - Starting Activity Timer
05:39:03,860  INFO BluSyncLauncher:557 - Load SystemTrayUI

05:39:10,612 **

> ERROR

** BackupPolicyDAOImpl:280 - SQLException while inserting backup policy details
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (BACKUP_POLICY.policyGroupName may not be NULL)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:342)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.execute(PrepStmt.java:65)
    at com.parablu.epa.common.dao.BackupPolicyDAOImpl.insertBackupPolicyDetailsToTable(BackupPolicyDAOImpl.java:273)
    at com.parablu.epa.common.service.settings.PolicyManagementServerHelper.createGroupPolicyAndChildDetails(PolicyManagementServerHelper.java:306)
    at com.parablu.epa.common.service.settings.PolicyManagementServerHelper.loadBackupPolicyElement(PolicyManagementServerHelper.java:245)
    at com.parablu.epa.service.backup.LinuxCheckBackupPolicy.checkGroupPolicy(LinuxCheckBackupPolicy.java:140)
    at com.parablu.epa.service.alarm.LinuxPolicyRefreshHelper$1.run(LinuxPolicyRefreshHelper.java:55)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Answer (score 0):

Loggers may be assigned levels. The set of possible levels, that is:

```
TRACE,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR and
FATAL
```

are defined in the [org.apache.log4j.Level](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) class. Although we do not encourage you to do so,

> you may define your own levels by sub-classing the Level class.

### Level Inheritance

A logging request is said to be enabled if its level is higher than or equal to the level of its logger. Otherwise, the request is said to be disabled. A logger without an assigned level will inherit one from the hierarchy. This rule is summarized below.

Basic Selection Rule

> A log request of level p in a logger with (either assigned or
>   inherited, whichever is appropriate) level q, is enabled if p >= q.

### UPDATE:

**In Log4j2 version 2.0.2**

If you wish to change the root logger level, do something like this :

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME); 
loggerConfig.setLevel(level);
ctx.updateLoggers();  // This causes all Loggers to refetch information from their LoggerConfig.
```

Comment: do i have to modify the levels how i have given in log4j.properties file?

Comment: You have to change it programmatically not in log4j.properties. You can go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level

Comment: i cannot set level like

Comment: LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG); i fi set this in my class it will log only debug info , i have given debug, info, error levels in class

Comment: my single class has all levels i cannot restrict it to one level

Comment: @adithyan.p you can update your loggers as you wanted. That I have updated in my answer. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

I get some information from [log4j filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html')

and read the log4j source code. I found it is possible.
Do like this:

```
appender.File.type=File
appender.File.name=infolog
appender.File.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.File.layout.pattern=%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.File.filename=${infologfilename}
#here! add filter named star, type is ThresholdFilter
appender.File.filter.star.type=ThresholdFilter
#level you want to filter
appender.File.filter.star.level=info
#if mathched the level, the log higher then the level will not output
appender.File.filter.star.onMatch=DENY
#if mismathed,output
appender.File.filter.star.onMisMatch=ACCEPT
```

May be it can help you.
I suggest you to use `xml configuration`,easy to read and edit.