# Hi,I am using log4j in my system.Is there a tag which automatically recognises change of level,so that i dont require to start stop my server

Tags: log4j, runtime

I am using log4j.xml to store my logs.
At runtime I need to change the level at production, and want to execute it by making changes in log4j.xml
I have used maxinterval but it does not reflect once I change my log levels.

I need to find a way to change my logger level at runtime at log4j.aml level.

Is it possible?

Comment: This may help ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level

Comment: Using the java approach,deletes my previous logs once my level is changed

Comment: <appender name="OrderHistoryLogging" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="100KB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
     <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    
     <!-- For Tomcat -->
    <param name="file" value="${DebugFilePath}/OrderHistoryLog.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern"
   value="%p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd} | %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} | %X{clientPrefix}| %t | %C : %L | %M | %m%n" />
    </layout>
 </appender>

Comment: this is my code .. As soon as I change my level my current file becomes of 0 KB and the previous logs are lost.I want to retain those logs.How should I do that