# how to change the log level of apache flink at runtime

Tags: logging, apache-flink

Is it possible to change the log level of the flink framework at runtime? when flink cluster is already running? I referred to the below document there is no such mention about it

```
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In the program code, Flink uses SLF4J for logging and supports log4j (log4j2 for Flink>= 1.11, log4j <  1.11) and Logback as underlying logging frameworks, which can be freely configured via their respective .properties files.

As far as I can tell, SLF4J itself doesn't support changing the logging level at runtime and in Flink itself, I see no custom code related to the underlying logging framework like log4j or logback which would change the loglevel via some mechanism like a REST API.

That said, the log framework itself might allow for some mechanism to change the log level at runtime. On a short google search, I find that for instance log4j has some mechanisms included e.g. by using File Watchdog and reload logging properties files at runtime, see for example here: [Dynamically Changing log4j log level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598702/dynamically-changing-log4j-log-level)
Of course, you would need to build the tooling around that yourself, i.e. find out where your TaskManagers and JobManagers are running, have their working directory and provide/edit the files accordingly.

Conclusion: I'd suggest you to stop your job with a savepoint, change the logging properties and restart the job. That's probably the easier way to go..

Comment: Logback has the same feature. It checks file for changes (interval can be configured) and apply new configuration.